# Uninstall Resharper completely

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have completely uninstalled the resharper. But still it shows on VS 2013 menu.Could you tell me how to remove it completely ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely remove new .NET tools from Visual Studio, please try the following:

Run ReSharper 9.x (new .NET Tools) installer once again - do you have any products with status Repair? If so, please select Remove for them and select Skip for others.

If there are no items with Repair action, please remove the following folder manually `C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{Visual Studio version}\Extensions\JetBrains`

[Solution](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545359-Uninstalling-new-NET-Tools-from-Visual-Studio)